# How to delegate touch events on both popup window and activity android

Tags: android, popup, popupwindow, touch-event

I have an activity which is having two buttons and a popup window.By click a button popup will display. I want to handle touch events in both popup window and activity.
In the below image i want to handle Ok button click with out dismiss the popup widow. At the same time i need dismiss button event as well.

I have tried

popWindow.setTouchable(true); then activity events are not working.

popWindow.setTouchable(false); then popup window events are not working.

Please see the image for reference.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `WindowManager`.

```
private void popUp(View yourPopUpView,WindowManager.LayoutParams params){
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    manager.addView(yourPopUpView,params);
}
```

remove same view using

```
private void removePopUp(View yourPopUpView){
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    manager.removeView(yourPopUpView);
}
```

but don't forget to remove that view onResume of your activity. B'coz it will remain after destroy of your activity also..

Hope this helps...